# Debugging - object instance

Tags: c++, debugging

So far, all I use debugging for is to know in which line an exception happens and what values the members. I don't get what's the use of watching an object like this:

```
Name Variable
objA 0x10cf990
```

Even before the cursor reach the line, objA contains a garbage value. What's the point if you can't read the value? And is there a way to see the data of an object?

For example,

```
class A{
  name = "im a";

  String getName(){
     return name;
  }
}

main(){
   A* objA = new A(); //breakpoint here
}
```

On debug, can I see the values of the members and the returned values of functions of objA?

Like

```
Name Variable
objA 0x10cf990
--name im a
--getName() im a
```

I think I have tried something like this before. I'm not so sure.

System: Linux Mint 15 64bit
IDE: Kdevelop4 (I think its debugger is GDB)

Comment: Which debugger (IDE) are you using? Hard to give you advice without knowing this!

Comment: Is your first question rhetorical?

Comment: I'm using Kdevelop4 in Linux Mint 15. I think its default debugger is gdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initially see garbage value in `objA` since it has not been initialized yet. Once you step ***over*** this line, it will change to a valid value.

```
A* objA = new A();
```

The new valid value may seem garbage to you too, but remember that `objA` is a pointer to A, so the garbage-like value is actually a valid memory address.

> On debug, can I see the values of the members and the returned values
>   of functions of objA?

You can now expand `objA` in the Watch window, to see values of its members, which is `name` in this case. Keep in mind that you may be able to see value of `name` before objA is initialized, but again, that would be a garbage value.

I don't know if KDevelop supports watching functions. But you can do this in Visual C++. To watch returned values of functions, you add the function call to the Watch window, for example:

```
objA->getName()
```

Beware when watching functions in the Watch window, if the function modifies data, it may create side effects and confuse you.

Comment: I know it's a memory address, I'm just confused 'cause I don't know how to fully use Kdevelop's debugger yet and I don't know if Kdevelop supports watching members or functions of objects. I will check it out later. Thank you.